# How to keep all activeDots always "active" rather than hovering over data points (recharts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have the package "recharts" (latest version 1.5.0) from npm installed and properly loaded with data on my react project.

Data lines and chart are always active. I need all the "activeDots" to always be active rather than active only when hovering over data points.

```
   <LineChart
        width={240}
        height={180}
        data={data}
        margin={{top: 15, right: 10, left: 10}}
      >
         <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} />
         <XAxis
          dataKey="x"
          stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"
          strokeWidth=".4"
          scale="time"
          type="number"
          domain={['auto', 'auto']}
          tick={{fontSize: 12}}
          tickFormatter = {(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('MMM D')}
         />
         <YAxis hide={true} />
         <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>}/>
         <Line
          connectNulls={false}
          type="linear"
          dataKey="pv"
          stroke="#3F99F7"
          strokeWidth="3"
          activeDot={{ fill: '#3F99F7', stroke:'#fff', strokeWidth: 3, r: 11, className: "boxShadow" }}
          dot={{ fill: '#3F99F7', stroke:'#fff', strokeWidth: 2, r: 7, className: "boxShadow" }}
         />
      </LineChart>
```

not hovering over data points:
[image: not hovering]

hovering over data point: 
[image: hovering]

Answer (score 1):

This looks about like what you want (the purple line):

```js
const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
 render () {
   return (
     <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line 
        type="monotone" 
        dataKey="pv" 
        stroke="#8884d8" 
        activeDot={{ fill: '#3F99F7', stroke:'#fff', strokeWidth: 3, r: 11, className: "boxShadow" }}
          dot={{ fill: '#3F99F7', stroke:'#fff', strokeWidth: 2, r: 7, className: "boxShadow" }}
        />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/prop-types/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/recharts/umd/Recharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Which is the same code more or less that you have in your example, which leads me to believe there may be something more going on in your code that you haven't located.

Comment: Good point, though I don't see how anything else could be effecting the package on changing the way the "activeDot" actives.

Comment: @AliMansour I know SSR and the responsive container can affect the render of the dots

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Do I need to compare the codes to see what is the difference? Can you explain what you did and how it solves the problem?